# Emit existing signal with custom type

Tags: python, pyside

I would like to "increase" an existing signal (`currentIndexChanged` in example above) to make it able to return another type:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MyClass(object):
    pass

class MyClassComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):

    @QtCore.Signal(int, result=MyClass)
    def currentIndexChanged(self, *args):

        my_class_instance = self._id_to_my_class(args[0])

        return my_class_instance


class MyClassWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClassWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        cb = MyClassComboBox(self)

        cb.currentIndexChanged[MyClass].connect(self.do_it)

    def do_it(self, *args):

        assert isinstance(args[0], MyClass)

        print args
```

As you guess, this code doesn't work because of `@QtCore.Signal(int, result=MyClass)`. As you guess, the idea is to register an existing signal (`currentIndexChanged`) to return a given, custom type (`MyClass`).

Any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: You emit your own custom signal when the index is changed and connect to that.

Answer (score 0):

Messing with existing `Qt` signals doesn't sound like a good idea. If you need to pass additional or modified arguments to a slot when a signal is emitted, you can do so with a lambda function.

While it's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve from your example, you probably want something like this

```
cb.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda i: self.do_it(MyClass(i)))
```